# Python/Pandas Merge rows into one row and decide what operation to do in each column

Tags: python, pandas, merge, row

I have a Pandas DataFrame (data) with columns ['Date' (datetime), 'Hours Worked' (timedelta), 'Pay' (float), 'Pay per Hour' (float), 'Distance' (float), 'Minimum Salary' (float)]

**How can I combine rows into 1 row, based on a column value that is the same for all, but assign how to calculate values of the other columns?**
I want to combine rows based on same date `['Date'].dt.date`.
And assign different operations for each column.

For example, for columns 'Hours Worked' (sum), 'Pay' (sum), 'Pay per Hour' (average), 'Distance' (sum), 'Minimum Salary' (the lowest)]

I found the duplicated rows based on date:
`data[data['Date'].dt.date.duplicated()]`
but I am not sure how to combine the rows. Also, I checked some methods with groupby(), but I am not sure how can I use it in this case.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This sounds like a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).  Try `data.groupby("Date").agg({"Hours Worked": "sum", "Pay": "sum", "Pay per Hour": "mean", "Distance": "sum", "Minimum Salary": "min"})`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem, the following may help you.

You indeed can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to unify the rows based on the column that you have an interest in, but there is something missing.

First: It is good to have simulated data. Here is my code for that

```
dates = pd.date_range('10-01-2016', periods=50, freq='S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': 100 + np.random.randint(-5, 10, 100).cumsum(),
                  'value1': 75 + np.random.randint(-5, 10, 100).cumsum(),
                  'value2': 50 + np.random.randint(-5, 10, 100).cumsum(),
                  'value3': 25 + np.random.randint(-5, 10, 100).cumsum(),
                  'date': dates.append(dates)})
df = df.sort_values(by='date').set_index('date')
df.head()
```

[image]

Note that each date is duplicated.
Second: As you said, use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function, but in combination with the [aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) function, to the aggregation function you pass a dictionary with the keys as the columns of the DataFrame and the content as the function that you need, it should be something like this.

```
df.groupby("date").agg({"value":np.average,"value1":np.sum,"value2":np.std,"value3":np.diff}).head()
```

[image: df after goupby]

Hope it is what you need.